# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack, Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
import sys
def intro():
    print("description of quiz")
    choice1 = input("press A to login and B to signup ")
    choice1.lower()
    if choice1 == "b":
        signup()
    elif choice1 == "a":
        login()
    else:
        print("Error, invalid input")
        intro()

def signup():
    name = input("name ")
    age = input ("age ")
    year = input ("year ")
    username = name[:3] + age
    print("Your username is " + username + " ")
    password = str(input("desired password "))
    userinfo = open("userinfo.txt","a")
    userinfo.write(username + "," + password + "," + name + "," + age + "," + year + "\n")
    userinfo.close()
    quiztype()

def login():
    username1 = input("Please input your username ")
    userinfo = open("userinfo.txt","r")
    userinforec = userinfo.readline()
    while userinforec != "":
        field = userinforec.split(",")
        username = field[0]
        password = field[1]
        name = field[2]
        age = field[3]
        year = field[4]
        if username == username1:
            password1 = str(input("What is your password? "))
            if password == password1:
                print("password accepted")
                quiztype()
            else:
                print("Error, password not accepted")
                login()
        userinforec = userinfo.readline()#ooooooooooooooooooooooooCOME BACK TO DO THE ELSE ERROR IF USERNAMES NOT EQUALooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
    userinfo.close()

def quiztype():
    quiztype = input("Choose maths or history? ")
    quiztype.lower()
    if quiztype == "maths":
        print("You have chosen maths")
        difficulty()
    elif quiztype == "history":
        print("You have chosen history")
        difficulty()
    else:
        print("Error, invalid input")
        quiztype()
    return quiztype

def difficulty():
    diff = input("Choose easy, medium, or hard ")
    diff.lower()
    if diff == "easy":
        print("You have chosen easy")
    elif diff == "medium":
        print("You have chosen medium")
    elif diff ==  "hard":
        print("You have chosen hard")
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
        difficulty()
    return diff

def typeoffile():
    if quiztype() == "maths":
        topicfile = "maths.txt"
    else:
        topicfile = "history.txt"
    return topicfile

def questionstolist():
    questionfile = open(typeoffile(),"r")
    qrec = questionfile.readline()
    for line in qrec:
        question, rightanswer, wrong1, wrong2, wrong3, wrong4 =      line.strip().split(",")#problem is here
    print(question)#^problem is here^
```

In the function, questionstolist(), I run the code and it comes up with the following error: ValueError:need more than 1 value to unpack.
I have read up on this error and I have rectified what I thought was the error however it did not work. In my file there are 6 sections separated by commas (5+5,10,11,17,5,12) and there are 6 variables that need to be assigned.

Comment: `line.strip().split(",")` clearly does not return a list of 6 items. You might want to print it first to check: `print(line.strip().split(","))`

Comment: `readline()` reads a single line - `qrec`, which will be a string.  You then iterate through the string, so `line` will be a single character!  I suggest you replace `for line in qrec:` with `for line in questionfile:`, and remove the `readline()`.